# How to extract just username in XpathQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath

When I do

```
ListunitUsers[@UID='LIST2']
```

I get

```
<root>
  <ListunitUsers>
    <ListunitMembership Note="" SortId="0">
      <Users id="778" username="wa" email="">
        <profile_guest profile="162">
          <address aid="159"/>
        </profile_guest>
      </Users>
    </ListunitMembership>
  </ListunitUsers>
</root>';
```

but what I would really want is just to get the username.

How do I extract just the username?

Comment: Provide XML to which you apply XPath query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the line of

```
ListunitUsers[@UID='LIST2']/ListUnitMembership/Users/@username
```

UPDATE:

Aha, it is [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226440%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and an XPath query against relational data. It supports neither the root node ('/'), nor the attribute axis. So your best bet is to extract the <Users> node an read the username attribute directly, however that is done.

Comment: When I do that I get the error `XPath: unable to find /ListunitUsers/Users in the schema`. Is that a permission problem?

Comment: I have no idea. To what, exactly, are you applying this XPath?

Comment: It looks like you dropped the ListunitMembership node out of the expression. Try /ListunitUsers/ListunitMembership/Users instead.

Comment: I must have typed something wrong before, because now I get the error `XPath: only direct object access may select an attribute. Either change the XPath to select an element, or else use direct object access` when I use forty-two's query.

Comment: OK, so you are using something with limited XPath support. What is it? The suspense is killing us! ;-)

Comment: @forty-two Good question =) I have no idea, what the backend is. All I have is a web interface, which I access through Perl and dump the output. Can I type something to make the backend identify itself?

Comment: @forty-two Error messages mentions `Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlException`. What would have been the correct backend, so I had all the XPath functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
"//root/ListunitUsers/Listunitmembership.Users[@username]"
```

You will find this helpful: [W3 Schools Xpath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: It must be an old version I am using as I get `XPath: the descendant-or-self axis is not supported`